# Category with translation

Tags: category-theory

Let $C$ be a category with a translation $\tau:C\rightarrow C$ (i.e, an equivalence of categories). I've been trying to show that if $C$ is additive then $\tau$ is an additive functor.
I tried to show that $\tau$ preserves direct sums but I've not been successful in this idea.

Thank you in advance if you can give me some idea of how solve it by this way or some hint in another direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any equivalence of categories preserves all limits and colimits that exist.